How to include product reviews as part of vertext ai search for retail?
I have a working product catalog with Google vertex AI for retail.
However, through documentation thee is no mention on how to incorporate product reviews for text search. This is very important parameter for us.
What is the best way to incorporate this? There is no mention on adding this as part of product catalog schema. One possible way is to add summary in tags fields in schema but this might loose some important parts of complete reviews.

When you send the product data to Vertex AI (via create or import), there's a field for ratings in the payload https://cloud.google.com/retail/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects.locations.catalogs.branches.products#Product
After that, go to the console, Attribute Controls and make sure the ratings are set as Retrievable (this may take a few hours to be seen in the response). After that, just perform a search and the ratings info should be included

To incorporate product reviews for text search. You may use search requests to get results for both text searches and browse searches. To make a search request, use the servingConfigs.search method.
Vertex AI Search for retail lets you provide high quality product search results that are customizable for your retail business needs. Leverage Google's query and contextual understanding to improve product discovery across your website and mobile applications.
